# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FALSE' When removing empty string from a dataset

Tags: python

```
with open(filename,'r') as input_file:
    
csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter = ',')
    
    for line_number, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if line_number == 0: # skip the header
            continue
        #if line[10] == '':
            #line.insert(10,0)
        my_dic.append({
            
            'First Name':line[11],
            'Last name':line[13],
            'Age(Years)':int(line[3]),
            'Sex':line[18],
            'type of car':line[16],
            'Marital Status':line[14],
            'Dependants':line[10],
            'Yearly Salary':int(line[17]),
            'Yearly Pension':int(line[15]),
            'Company':line[5],
            'Commuted Distance':float(line[4]),
            'vehicle':{
                'Make':line[19],
                'model':line[20],
                'year':int(line[21]),
                'category':line[22]
                
            },
            'Credit Card':{
                'Start Date':line[6],
                'End Date':line[7],
                'Card number':line[8],
                'Card CCV':int(line[9]),
                'iban':line[12]
                
            },
            'Address':{
                'Street':line[0],
                'City':line[1],
                'Postcode':line[2]
            }
            
            
            
        })
```

I have the code above converting csv file to dictionary, and I also want to replace the empty strings in column 10 of the dataset. If I remove the commented code (the code that tries to replace the empty string in column 10 (of the data) with a number, my code works. However, if I remove the comment, it gives value error at 'yearly salary' key that I typecast to integers)

1.How else can I replace empty string in the column with a number (I don't want to use pandas)

2. I also want know the rows where the correction takes place

Comment: That is correct. I should have used assignment statement . It didn't eventually worked with .. if line[10]== None . So, I used if line[10]==" as written and it catches all the line with empty strings . I guessed  '' is different from None in python . Secondly I intended using a reader not a DictReader, a reason i indexed with numbers instead of column name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line.insert(10,0)` inserts additional value to the array. For example, if the array was length 20, after `insert`, it will be of length 21. You get wrong values, and on position 17, you get a non-integer value.

You want to replace the value, not insert it.

```
line[10] = 0
```

However, it would be easier to understand the code if the conversion is done in the dictionary itself.

```
{
...
"Dependants": line[10] or 0,
...
}
```

2. To get the line number, the easiest way is to store `line_number` to some array... For example,

```
missing_data_on_dependants_row_idxs = list()
for line_number, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if line_number == 0: # skip the header
        continue
    if line[10] is None:
        missind_data_on_dependants_row_idxs.append(line_number)
...
```

Also, referring to the columns by indexes is hard to understand. Did you consider using `csv.DictReader`?

Comment: .That is correct. I should have used assignment statement . It didn't eventually worked with  if line[10]==None . So I used if line[10]==" as written and it catches all the line with empty strings  as above . I guessed  '' is different from None in python . Secondly I intended using a reader not a DictReader, a reason i indexed with numbers instead of column name . My code is not returning error anymore but the typecast i did on Dependants  after the correction did not convert the Dependant  to int type in the dictionary . I am still having a string . Is there anything I can do further ?

Comment: `'Dependants': int(line[10]),` maybe?